# Login control's login button enabled/disabled property in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, controls

Just wondered how to enable/disable "log in" button on a login control based on if User Name and Password textboxes are null or not ? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Hi Jack
First convert the login control into template and then add the following jquery code in header section of the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('input[type="text"]').keypress(function () {
                if ($(this).val != '') {
                    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            });
        });
```